# Strange If, Elif, Else behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

If I use the any of the following conditions on its own, it works as expected. (see Larger code block for all conditions). I do get the following `exception` printed when I expect the `(df['ColumnName'] == 'This Value').any():` to fire.

Exception printed `'ColumName2'` This prints 3 times, so that tells me one of the conditions is being met, its just not firing :$

**Works on its own**

```
if filename.endswith('.csv'):
    print 'File is CSV'        
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,filename), skip_blank_lines=True)
    try:
        if (df['ColumnName'] == 'This Value').any():
           final_df = df.drop(df.ix[df['ColumnName'] == 'This Value'].index)
           data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
           data.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Edit.csv"), index=False, na_rep="NA")
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

But when used in a larger `if`, `elif`, `else` none seem to work (not even the else is hit). The syntax seems to be correct and none of the answer on StackOverflow that I have seen seem to cover this. None of the conditions are the same so don't see any issues there, I'm not entirely sure what is causing the problem.

**Larger if, elif, else**

```
if filename.endswith('.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,filename), skip_blank_lines=True)
        try:
            if (df['ColumnName'] == 'That Value').any():
                print 'ColumnName and "That Value"'
                final_df = df.drop(df.ix[df['ColumnName'] == 'This Value'].index)
                data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
                data.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Edit.csv"), index=False, na_rep="NA")

            elif (df['ColumnName2'] == 'This Value').any():
                print 'ColumnName2 This Value'
                final_df = df.drop(df.ix[df['ColumnName2'] == 'This Value'].index)
                data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
                data.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Edit.csv"), index=False, na_rep="NA")

            elif ((df['ColumnName2']=='That Value')).any():
                print 'ColumnName2 That Value'
                final_df = df[df['Dst Port'] != 'Any']
                data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
                data.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Edit.csv"), index=False, na_rep="NA")

            elif ((df['ColumnName']=='This Value')).any():
                print 'ColumnName This Value'
                final_df = df[df['Service'] != 'Any']
                data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
                data.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Edit.csv"), index=False, na_rep="NA")

            else:
                print 'No Filtering Applied'
                data = df.sort(ascending=True)
                data.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Edit.csv"), index=False, na_rep="NA")
         except Exception as e:
             print e
```

**Fix Thanks to AnandSKumars Comments**

```
if filename.endswith('.csv'):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,filename), skip_blank_lines=True)
        if 'ColumnName' in df and (df['ColumnName'] == 'This Value').That Value():
            print 'Service and This Value'
            final_df = df.drop(df.ix[df['ColumnName'] == 'This Value'].index)
            data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
            with open(os.path.join(root,'Edit.csv'), 'a') as f:
                data.to_csv(f, index=False, na_rep="NA")
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, filename))

        elif 'ColumnName2' in df and (df['ColumnName2'] == 'This Value').That Value():
            print 'ColumnName2 and This Value'
            final_df = df.drop(df.ix[df['ColumnName2'] == 'This Value'].index)
            data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
            with open(os.path.join(root,'Edit.csv'), 'a') as f:
                data.to_csv(f, index=False, na_rep="NA")
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, filename))

        elif 'ColumnName2' in df and ((df['ColumnName2']=='That Value')).That Value():
            print 'ColumnName2 and That Value'
            final_df = df[df['ColumnName2'] != 'That Value']
            data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
            with open(os.path.join(root,'Edit.csv'), 'a') as f:
                data.to_csv(f, index=False, na_rep="NA")
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, filename))

        elif 'ColumnName' in df and ((df['ColumnName']=='That Value')).That Value():
            print 'Service and That Value'
            final_df = df[df['ColumnName'] != 'That Value']
            data = final_df.sort(ascending=True)
            with open(os.path.join(root,'Edit.csv'), 'a') as f:
                data.to_csv(f, index=False, na_rep="NA")
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, filename))

        else:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, filename))
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: does the else statement match the indentation of the elif statements? the else statement can be used together with the try statement, so you have to be careful.

Comment: You have an inconsistent indentation on the second example. `try` block should be at the same column that `df = [...]` and `except`. `else` block should also be on the same column than `if` and `elif` Not sure it will resolve your issue, but cost nothing to try ;)

Comment: Apologies that is just a mismatch when moving code to post. Will amend now. All indents are correct in real code

Comment: Did you verify if no exception is thrown by `df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,filename), skip_blank_lines=True)` ?

Comment: yip that works fine to, it was in the try statement before I moved it out to try work out what the issue was.

Comment: Nothing gets printed? Not even any exception?

Comment: When you get data from dictionary if key is not present and you try to access it throws error so it directly goes to Exception block, So now  instedof df['ColumnName'] you can use fd.get("ColumnName",None) then it work fine with try also.

Comment: I get three exceptions printed `'ColumnName'`. This is expected as not all conditions will be met. None of the `print` statements fire. But as mentioned if i use the `if` on their own it works as expected. Its very wierd :$

Comment: can you update the question what are the exceptions that get printed?

Comment: What happens when you check if the column you are trying to check is in the dataframe or not using `'ColumnName' in df`

Comment: @AnandSKumar what do you mean? Currently it throws an exception if `ColumnName` doesnt exist.

Comment: Can you please let the *full* exception bubble up? What you're giving now is a vague indicator, which points to one of two lines, but even that's uncertain. The full exception will likely have the full offending line in it. Don't catch an exception if you can't recover from it.

Comment: @Evert that is the full exception print im afraid. `e` prints `'ColumnName'`

Comment: No, that's not the full exception. A full exception would come with a traceback. Replace `print e` with `raise` and see what you get.

Comment: Do this for each condition - `if 'ColumnName' in df and (df['ColumnName'] == 'That Value').any():`

Comment: Removing the catch I get KeyError: 'ColumnName2' on the first if as I would expect as that doesnt have `ColumnName` in it.

Comment: You likely still have a mismatch somewhere in your indentation; either a missed single space, or a mismatch between spaces and tabs.

Comment: @Evert ive never had any mismatch in the indentations as described earlier.

Comment: KeyError where? You're still not showing the full traceback, and there are multiple uses of 'ColumnName2'.

Comment: @iNoob Do this for each condition - `if 'ColumnName' in df and (df['ColumnName'] == 'That Value').any():` , and let us know

Comment: @AnandSKumar Now Im getting a `elif` to fire, the second one. But it throws an error later on in the script. However your suggested change has made me think of what it could be. Im going to go test it quick and will let you know.

Comment: @iNoob : please re-read **and apply** Evert's recommandations - in fact just get rid of that whole  try/except which is more than useless. Then learn to read a traceback.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The line causing the exception has been identified as mentioned above already and is expected. Im getting the exception in the places I would expect as mentioned already aswell. The traceback wont be any good as I and everyone else on the thread already knows where the exceptions are and that they are expected as Ive already mention it. I have worked out the problem thanks to the comments by AnandSKumar. I will post the fix shortly

Comment: Once changes suggested by @AnandSKumar were made I could see the condition being met but I was getting errors else where. Each time the condition was met the file being written was over written. So AnandSKumars comment fixed the issue. Can you please create an answer Anand. Although I had errors later (also now fix), you comment suggestion made the relevant condition fire.

Comment: and to whom ever gave the `-1` im sure we know who you are ;) there is nothing wrong with my question everyone else seemed to understand it fine :) but thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: Added an answer :-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the issue is that you have some csv files, that do not have some of the column in that csv. Hence after reading it into the dataframe, when you try to do `df['ColumnName']` it errors out by giving - `KeyError: 'ColumnName'` . Which indicates that the `'ColumnName'` does not exist in the DataFrame.

But once the error occurs, it is caught by the `try..except` block and hence none of the other `if` or `elif` conditions fire, and hence you are not able to see the output.

If you want only one of the conditions to meet , then you can check if the column you are trying get is part of the df or not. Example -

```
if 'ColumnName' in df and (df['ColumnName'] == 'That Value').any():
```

Similarly for other `if` conditions.